# Google Big Query Flatten table and use table_range function

Tags: google-bigquery, flatten

Does anyone know how to use multiple FLATTEN function and Table_date_range at the same time? Now I can only get one day data, but I would like to have all the data that are available. Is there a way to do it?

```
select 
Date,COUNT(DISTINCT FULLVISITORID),hits.product.v2ProductCategory
FROM FLATTEN((FLATTEN (table, hits.product.v2ProductCategory)) ,customDimensions.value)
group by Date
,hits.product.v2ProductCategory
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below (not tested)

```
SELECT 
  DATE,
  COUNT(DISTINCT FULLVISITORID),
  hits.product.v2ProductCategory
FROM FLATTEN(FLATTEN (
  (SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([aaprod-20160309:112099209.ga_sessions_],
        TIMESTAMP('2016-07-25'),
        TIMESTAMP('2016-07-27'))
  ), hits.product.v2ProductCategory), customDimensions.value
)
GROUP BY 
  DATE, 
  hits.product.v2ProductCategory
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail. It works for me in Google Big query. However, when I put the query in Tableau, I got this error "Syntax error: Expected "]" but got ":" at [1:599] ". I guess I have to use standard sql not legacy sql if I want to put the query in Tableau.

Comment: Standard SQL is the preferred dialect for interacting with BigQuery. See also [Tableau's support page for BigQuery](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_googlebigquery.html) and [the standard SQL reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

Comment: totally agree with Elliott. Meantime If there is a specific question specifically about Legacy SQL feature - I think it still make sense to provide direct answer. Whenever context of question is not clear/available - as it was initially with this question  - just recommending to move to Standard SQL make not much sense to me  - that's why I didn't. But still  - totally agree with Elliott and his comment above! Standard SQL is the preferred way (vs. Legacy) to deal with :o)BigQuery

Answer (score 6):

You should use standard SQL instead. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT FULLVISITORID),
  product.v2ProductCategory,
  customDimension.value
FROM `aaprod-20160309.112099209.ga_sessions_*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimension
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.product) AS product
GROUP BY 1, 3, 4;
```

The differences between legacy and standard SQL are described in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: Hi Elliott, Thank you for your answer. However, when I run the query, I got an error code:Column name customDimensions is ambiguous. I tried to work around it. but haven't found the answer yet. Any thought?

Comment: I think you may need to change it to:

FROM `aaprod-20160309.112099209.ga_sessions_*` AS t

and:

CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimension

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. now it's another error: Cannot access field v2ProductCategory on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<productSKU STRING, v2ProductName STRING, v2ProductCategory STRING, ...>>. I am new to Google Big Query, I am sorry if I have too many questions.

Comment: You may need to "flatten" that as well, e.g. add `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.product) AS product` and then refer to `product.v2ProductCategory` in the select list. Feel free to post another question if you need more help, though, since it might be easier to discuss the query that way.

Comment: Hi Elliott, I posted another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580589/unnesthit-ecommerceaction-google-bigquery Please take a look when you have time. Thank you

Comment: Hi Elliott, Another question I would like to ask is does my query show the result of how many unique visitors viewed a certain product?

Comment: This will give you a count of unique visitors broken down by day, product category, and the custom dimension value. If you just wanted a daily visitor count by product, for instance, you could remove `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimension` and also `customDimension.value` from the select (and group by) list.