# UNNEST(hit.eCommerceAction), Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I used the same logic to unnest hit.eCommerceAction, but it's not working as other fields. Any help on this problem? Also, Is the max(if()) function the right function to use to get two hits.customeDimenison.value?

```
SELECT
 Date
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT FULLVISITORID)
 , product.v2ProductCategory

  ,max(if(customDimensions.index=2, customDimensions.value,null))  as dest
  ,max(if(customDimensions.index=21, customDimensions.value,null))  as pax
 ,eCommerceAction.action_type
 ,product.v2ProductName

FROM `table` as t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimensions
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.eCommerceAction) as eCommerceAction
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.product) AS product
GROUP BY 
      Date
      ,product.v2ProductCategory
    ,eCommerceAction.action_type
,product.v2ProductName
```

The Error code I am getting is Error: Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with a simpler query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT hit.eCommerceAction.action_type 
FROM `73156703.ga_sessions_20170109` t
  , UNNEST(hits) hit
  , UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) customDimensions
  , UNNEST(hit.eCommerceAction) as eCommerceAction
```

The issue here is that `eCommerceAction` is not a `REPEATED` record, hence there is no array to `UNNEST`.

Fixed query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT hit.eCommerceAction.action_type 
FROM `ga_sessions_20170109`  t
  , UNNEST(hits) hit
  , UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) customDimensions
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, Thank you so much for you response. It works for me. Just out of curiosity, do know any of the website/tutorials that I can go and learn more about google big query?

Comment: Hello! Depends on what you are looking for, but everything I learn about BigQuery, I post to http://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look after I finish this report. :)