# BigQuery - CASE WHEN x IN (field from other table), results in Semijoin error

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to segment website visitors by whether or not they have ever purchased from us before. When I put in the below field in the SELECT statement, I get the further below error:

```
CASE WHEN fullVisitorId IN (SELECT fullVisitorId FROM [xxxx-0000:36363.unique_FullVisitorIds_of_past_purchasers_table]) THEN "Purchased"
ELSE "Never Purchased" END AS Previous_Purchase
```

Error: "Error: (L10:20): Semijoin expression (i.e. "x IN (SELECT ...)") only supported in WHERE or HAVING clauses."

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), which is more flexible about joins? You will have to make some updates to your syntax such as for the table name, as described in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Switching to Standard SQL introduces some other problems for me, so I've just gone with the join as mentioned below. Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain what the problems are?

Comment: Its a pretty involved query, the switch to standard sql somehow required me to unnest the eCommerceAction field. "Error: Cannot access field eCommerceAction on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [39:21]"
I don't really know how to use unnest() and think it might cause further problems in the rest of the query. thats why i just went with the other way.

Comment: Turns out the issue I had with unnesting after switching to Standard SQL was solved in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580589/unnesthit-ecommerceaction-google-bigquery)

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote (in fact I never do) so it must have been someone else, sorry :( I'm glad that you found a solution in any case.

Comment: oh, no worries. I didn't think you did. Just thought whoever did might get a comment notification to come and explain their reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest joining a summarized result along these lines:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN p.has_purchased = 1 THEN "Purchased"
         ELSE "Never Purchased" 
    END AS Previous_Purchase
FROM existing_from_table f
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fullVisitorId, 1 has_purchased
    FROM [xxxx-0000:36363.unique_FullVisitorIds_of_past_purchasers_table]
    GROUP BY fullVisitorId
    ) p on f.fullVisitorId = p.fullVisitorId
```

nb: The group by is used so that the overall number of rows is not affected.